# Dom4j not working after building android app

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an android app that uses java and ive been trying to use dom4j Document to parse some XML files. The XML is provides as text such as

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document document = reader.read(new StringReader(xmlText));
```

This all works fine in the compiler but does not work after building but i see no build warnings or errors related to this. I have seen a few posts online about compatibility with doc4j and android but im unsure why this would be failing.

Here is the dependency im using

```
implementation 'org.dom4j:dom4j:2.1.3'
```

And here are the proguard rules

```
-keep class org.dom4j.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.dom4j.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.dom4j.**
-dontwarn org.xml.sax.**
-keep class org.xml.sax.**{*;}
```

I have tried to use string editing to get this task done as well as XMLPull parse but those are quite more verbose and hard to use and im struggling to convert my code to work properly with those.

So far i have tried a variety of progruard rules and trying to re-write the code using the build in xml parser tools but that has not been going well.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed just needed to add these proguard rules

```
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-keep class org.w3c.dom.**{*;}
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-keep class javax.xml.**{*;}
```